# UI to Web Services communication with custom authorization using .NET technologies

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authorization, soa

I'm trying to design a web application that would user WCF services to access data and provide business logic. So in general the whole system would look like that:

```
UI (ASP.NET MVC)
BusinessLayer (WCF Services)
DataLayer (Entity Framework)
Date (SQL Server Database)
```

All parts of the system will resist on the same, closed environment, so I'm going to use Certificates to secure `ASP.NET <-> WCF` connection. Database connection would use standard EF securities, Connection String and Windows Authentication.

The application has to provide authentication and authorization functionality. I'm going to move most of that into ASP.NET, so there will be `ValidateUserAuth()` service method, which will be used to validate credentials, but the result (with `UserRole` that user belongs to) will be then used by ASP to create user session.

After that, every Service Method call needs to know the UserRole of current user, to return proper results (or say 'Access denied' if it's necessary). **Problem is I don't want to pass that `UserRole` as a parameter for every Service Method!** I'd like to make it happen automatically. Is it even possible with WCF?

All I need is:

- Every service call made from ASP.NET app will be extended with User data taken from current ASP Session.
- Service Method invoked by that call will be able to recieve that User data and use it to provide results according to user permissions.
- All this would happen somekind on background, so there will be no additional `UserDetails` method parameter added to every Service Method exposed from Service.

I read a lot about WCF itself, but found anything that could met my requirements. I hope I just missed it and it's still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use MessageInspector for that:

On Client-side:

```
Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, channel As System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel) As Object Implements System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest
    Dim requestMessageProperty = New HttpRequestMessageProperty()

    Dim currentUser = Authentication.AuthenticatedStaffcareUser

    If currentUser Is Nothing Then Throw New ApplicationException()

    requestMessageProperty.Headers("UserName") = currentUser.UserName
    requestMessageProperty.Headers("UserId") = currentUser.UserID
    requestMessageProperty.Headers("UserRole") = currentUser.UserRole
    requestMessageProperty.Headers("EffectiveDate") = currentUser.EffectiveDate
    request.Properties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = requestMessageProperty

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

And Server-side:

```
Public Function AfterReceiveRequest(ByRef request As Message, channel As IClientChannel, instanceContext As InstanceContext) As Object Implements IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest
    Dim messageProperty = CType(OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name), HttpRequestMessageProperty)

    Dim userName = messageProperty.Headers("UserName")
    Dim userId = Integer.Parse(messageProperty.Headers("UserId"))
    Dim userRole = messageProperty.Headers("UserRole")
    Dim effectiveDate = DateTime.Parse(messageProperty.Headers("EffectiveDate"))

    Dim identity = New AppServerUserIdentity(userName, userId, userRole, effectiveDate)
    Dim principal = New AppServerUserPrincipal(identity)

    Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I also had to set custom AuthorizationPolicy to prevent standard one from overwriting Thread.CurrentPrincipal:

```
Public Function Evaluate(evaluationContext As EvaluationContext, ByRef state As Object) As Boolean Implements IAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate

    Dim principal = TryCast(Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal, AppServerUserPrincipal)

    If principal Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    Else
        evaluationContext.Properties("Principal") = principal
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing user roles from the client to the server in a plain form would be a design mistake. Clients could easily misuse your services by calling them freely, outisde of the application scope.

Why don't you rely on a role provider? This way all you pass from the client is the identity (could even be a forms cookie) and then at the server side you read all roles. You could probably even use a built in mechanism to cache roles in a role cookie.

Some time ago I wrote two tutorials on wcf securing with forms authentication so that integration between web pages and active clients is easy

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/02/clickonce-webservice-and-shared-forms.html

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-forms-authentication-sharing-for.html

Comment: WCF Service will be closed so there would be no possibility to call it directly from internet. Doesn't it make passing userId or userRole in a plain form valid?

Comment: What I think of is a request forgery threat where your api makes it possible to misuse it. I don't think it is relevant whether or not the api will be called from internet or from intranet - you still don't want users to be able to pretend they are administrators just as simple as calling a web method with specific combination of plain arguments.